# setting up ember-calender

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Hi I am trying to use ember-calender library

I did the following thing

1. `npm install ember-cli-moment`
2. `updated .jshintrc with moment: true`
3. `npm install ember-cli-calendar` from emberaddons.com site

and
in login.hbs

```
<h2>Login</h2>
{{ember-calendar
    eventsMode=eventsMode
    gridMode='month'
    allEvents=eventList
}}
```

I am getting error

```
Uncaught Error: <venuehunt@view:default::ember522> Handlebars error: Could not find property 'ember-calendar' on object <venuehunt@controller:login::ember396>. 
VM204:993ProfileManager.ended VM204:993flush 
VM204:2067fn vendor.js:13478DeferredActionQueues.invoke 
vendor.js:13808DeferredActionQueues.flush vendor.js:13858Backburner.end 
vendor.js:13321Backburner.run vendor.js:13376executeTimers 
vendor.js:13701(anonymous function)
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue the other day.

It appears that Ember does not see the addon 'ember-calendar' and tries to look it up as a property from controllers.

The solution was adding the addon to project's package.json devDependencies:

```
{
  ....
  "ember-cli-calendar": "*"
}
```

A shortcut for adding would be:

```
npm install ember-cli-calendar --save-dev
```

Hope this helps!